# R openNLPmodels.en package no longer available?

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp

the R package openNLPmodels.en used to be available from https://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/openNLPmodels.en_1.5-1.tar.gz but this url no longer works... Does anyone know if it's available anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The model files for English and various other languages are still available.

When you open https://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/ in a browser of your choice, you will find the file you are looking for.